# Dynamic mapping

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, restkit

I have JSON response.body

```
{"0":
      {"id":724,
      "firstName":"Dr. Anna-Maria",
      "lastName":"Boehler (Bohler)",
      "city":"Luxembourg"},
    "1":
      {"id":1542,
      "firstName":"Joanna",
      "lastName":"Kotlewska (Biever)",
      "city":"Rodange"},
    "2":
      {"id":1681,
      "firstName":"Dr. Joanna",
      "lastName":"Louwagie (Hoche)",
      "city":"Luxembourg"},
    "3":
      {"id":2161,"firstName":"Magdalena",
      "lastName":"Sarrazin (Owsianna)",
      "city":"Luxembourg"},
    "4":
      {"id":10822,"firstName":"Anna",
      "lastName":"Kogut-Aramini",
      "city":"Diekirch"}
    ,"uri":"search-by-name",
    "paramsURL":{"country":"1","name":"Anna"}}
```

in AppDelegate add RKObjectMapping and RKDynamicMapping

```
RKObjectMapping *showListDoctorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ShowListResultResponse class]];
    [showListDoctorMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                                @"id" : @"id",
                                                                @"firstName" : @"firstName",
                                                                @"lastName" : @"lastName",
                                                                @"city" : @"city"
                                                                }];
    RKDynamicMapping *dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];
    [dynamicMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKObjectMapping *(id representation) {

        NSDictionary *dict = representation;
        NSArray *keys=[dict allKeys];
        RKObjectMapping *dataMapping =[RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ShowListResultResponse class]];
        for (NSString *key in keys){
            [dataMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:key mapping:showListDoctorMapping ];
        }
        return dataMapping;
    }];
```

ShowRensponse

and add ShowListResultResponse this class Mapping

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
class ShowListResultResponse: NSObject {

var id: Int?
var fristName: String?
var lastName: String?
var city: String?

override init() {
    super.init()
}

init(id: Int, fistName: String, lastName: String, city: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.fristName = fistName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.city = city
}
}
```

class DoctorsDataSource

```
import UIKit
class DoctorsDataSource: NSObject, MLPAutoCompleteTextFieldDataSource {

var listDoctors=[String]()
func autoCompleteTextField(textField: MLPAutoCompleteTextField!, possibleCompletionsForString string: String!, completionHandler handler: ([AnyObject]!) -> ()) {

    let appDelegate: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    var requestParameters: [NSObject:AnyObject] = [NSObject: AnyObject]()

    requestParameters["name"] = textField.text
    requestParameters["country"]="1"

    // Pobiera długość znaku textField
    let lenght = textField.text!.characters.count

    if lenght>3{
        let request = appDelegate.objectManager.requestWithObject(nil, method: .GET, path: "/search-by-name", parameters: requestParameters)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let operation  = appDelegate.objectManager.objectRequestOperationWithRequest(request, success: { (operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, rkmap: RKMappingResult!) in

            let list = rkmap.firstObject as AnyObject
            if let doctors = list as? [ShowListResultResponse]{
                //if let doctors = rkmap.array() as? [ShowListResultResponse]  {
                    for doctor: ShowListResultResponse in doctors {
                        self.listDoctors.append("\(doctor.fristName) \(doctor.lastName)")
                    }
                }

                handler(self.listDoctors);
            }) { (operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
                print("Load filed with error: @", error!)
                self.performSelectorOnMainThread(#selector(AppDelegate.showFetchError), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
            }
            appDelegate.objectManager.enqueueObjectRequestOperation(operation)
       // }
    }}
}
```

I don't know why don't show doctor list

Comment: You need to explain what happens with the code, how far does it work, what data do you get out? Preferably also only show the pertinent code...

Answer (score 0):

if am not familiar with that third party
But

1. you have a typo when using the firstName (fristName and fistName)
2. the JSON response is a dictionary with keys (string) and value (dictionary) and you try to read it as an Array

   **if let doctors = list as? [ShowListResultResponse]**

try to read it as a dictionary

```
if let dict = list as? [String:ShowListResultResponse]{
  let doctors = Array(dict.values)
}
```

you also might want to look into rkmap content

Comment: I use
library  MLPAutoCompleteTextField this library show autocomplete  DoctorsDataSource is class which get data firstname and surname  Doctros  when write name Doctor show result in autocomplete text